# Replacing words with shortcode function

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I´m looking for a little help here with a Wordpress function.

-What I want to build:
A shortcode I can use to replace a blank space with a predefined word, like this:

-What the visitor will see:
The grass is _______

-The shortcode I want to write on the post:
The grass is [blankspace: green]

-When the persona clicks the _______ it will be replaced by "green" as specified in shortcode tag.

I am very new with programing because I use to work on the front end, UX/UI, html and css and need a little help under the hood to present this idea.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
<div id="demo" onclick="myFunction()" >This is _____</div>

function myFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("_____", "Green");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;}
```

Comment: This is only one half of the problem. You should also consider using `this` rather than `.replace` within the `click` callback.

Comment: this is working code ... already tested .please mark it as answer

Comment: Thanks Yoyo, this is great, I was loonking for this interactive, but they key tomy problem is not only how to make it clickable, I m looking for a solution the could read the string inside the shortcode, then, replace the _______. 

The "green" string should be given by the shortcode, like: [shortcode "green"] ...that means I need a solution that will replace "______" by any string I could write instead of green. 

I am trying to get a text post with many ________ spaces and each space should be replaced by a different word. Thats why I'm trying to do this with shortcodes.

Thanks so much